# If we can use dataProvider using by extending class then why we are using dataProviderClass parameter in @Test annotation ? correct me if I wrong

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-annotation-test

// This is from another file but same package.

```java
public class EmpData 
{
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData()
    {
        Object[][] data= {{"Hello","text","1"},{"bye","Message","32"},{"solo","call","678"}}; 
        return data;
    }
}
```

// Type -1 ( This is from another file but the same package.)

```java
public class DPClass extends EmpData  
{
    @Test(dataProvider="getData")
    public void testCaseData(String Greeting, String Communication, String Id)
    {
        System.out.println(Greeting+Communication+Id);
    }
}
```

// Type -2

```java
public class DPClass  
{
    @Test(dataProvider="getData", dataProviderClass=DPClass.class)
    public void testCaseData(String Greeting, String Communication, String Id)
    {
        System.out.println(Greeting+Communication+Id);
    }
}
```

In above there are two separate file `DPClass.java` and `EmpData.java` in one single package we can provide data to `DPClass` in both way either add parameter in @Test annotation and by extending class with adding parameter in `@Test` annotation. If we are achieving this by extending class then why TestNG provided DataProviderClass? Correct me if I wrong for this concept, I need difference for both.

Answer (score 1):

That totally depends on how user needs to use it. If `dataProviderClass` option is not provided and if the user wants to keep data methods separate from the test methods, then the user is **forced** to extend the class as in your example.

```java
public class DPClass {
    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getData()
    {
        Object[][] data= {{"Hello","text","1"},{"bye","Message","32"},{"solo","call","678"}}; 
        return data;
    }
}

public class TestClass extends DPClass  
{
    @Test(dataProvider="getData")
    public void testCaseData(String Greeting, String Communication, String Id)
    {
        System.out.println(Greeting+Communication+Id);
    }
}
```

But imagine if your test class is already extending another class. So your test class cannot extend the `DPClass` (Classes in Java support single inheritance) and hence you can't keep data provider methods in a different class.

Example: For spring boot tests, if the test class requires spring application context, then the test class should extend `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`. So you cannot extend any more class.